# Overlaying a superset array onto a subset array where order/sequence matters (in Javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm

I have a set of arrays of the form

```
A= [1,2,3,4,5,6]
B= [7,8,9]
C= [5,6]
D= [9]
```

I want to "overlay" the right-sided (suffix) supersets (strictly speaking, super-sequences) on the subsets (subsequences) so that the result set looks like this:

```
A= [1,2,3,4,5,6] (unchanged, because not a subset of anything)
B= [7,8,9] (unchanged, because not a subset of anything)
C= [1,2,3,4,5,6] (C overlayed with A, because C is a subset of A)
D= [7,8,9] (D overlayed with B, because D is a subset of B)
```

I'm doing this in node.js. I think partly it is a logic problem that I'm failing to grasp. I

The real-world use case is merging path names in order to normalize a classification hierarchy that has many items with a mixture of full and truncated paths, e.g. /Science/Biology and /Biology gets normalized to /Science/Biology

Many thanks for any pointers to how to do this.

Comment: It took me several re-reads, but I got there. Interesting question.

Comment: If G is the subset of E and F, what G should become? Or it won't happen.

Comment: I think the longest parent should win. And maybe I need to iterate until there are no more mutations?

Comment: When you say subset, do you mean subsequence? Is it correct that `[1,2]` could expand to `[1,2,3]` but not to `[3,2,1]`?

Comment: Yes, thank you. Order matters. I will edit the q.

Comment: Also, are you only interested in suffix matches? It doesn't seem like it would be meaningful to convert `/Science` to `/Science/Biology` although it is a subsequence.

Comment: O good point. Yes. Only right-sided subsequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrote this in Haskell first just to get the algorithm down.

```
import Data.List (maximumBy, tails)
import Data.Map (Map, findWithDefault)
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as Map
import Data.Ord (comparing)

main :: IO()
main = putStrLn $ show $ normalize [[1..6], [7..9], [5..6], [9]]

normalize :: Ord a => [[a]] -> [[a]]
normalize xxs = map (\xs -> findWithDefault xs xs index) xxs
  where index = suffixIndex xxs

suffixIndex :: Ord a => [[a]] -> Map [a] [a]
suffixIndex xxs = Map.fromListWith (maxBy length) entries
  where entries = [ (suf, xs) | xs <- xxs, suf <- suffixes xs ]
        suffixes xs = drop 1 $ filter (not . null) $ tails xs

maxBy :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> a -> a -> a
maxBy f x y = maximumBy (comparing f) [x, y]
```

`suffixIndex` maps each suffix to the longest list having that suffix. So, for example `[[1,2,3], [2,3]]` results in an index that looks like `[2,3] -> [1,2,3], [3] -> [1,2,3]`.

Once the index is built, each list is "normalized" (to use your word) by just applying the map (if a mapping exists).

And now in Javascript.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(normalize([[1,2,3,4,5,6], [7,8,9], [5,6], [9]])));

function normalize(xxs) {
    var index = suffixIndex(xxs);
    return xxs.map(function (xs) {
        str = JSON.stringify(xs);
        return index.hasOwnProperty(str) ? index[str] : xs;
    });
}

function suffixIndex(xxs) {
    var index = {};
    xxs.forEach(function (xs) {
        suffixes(xs).forEach(function (suffix) {
            var str = JSON.stringify(suffix);
            index[str] = index.hasOwnProperty(str)
                ? maxBy(lengthOf, index[str], xs)
                : xs;
        });
    });
    return index;
}

function suffixes(xs) {
    var i, result = [];
    for (i = 1; i < xs.length; i++) result.push(xs.slice(i));
    return result;
}

function lengthOf(arr) { return arr.length; }

function maxBy(f, x, y) { return f(x) > f(y) ? x : y; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the most elegant way to do it, but comparing stringified versions will work.  Assuming you have `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` in an array `arr`:

```
function overlay (arr) {
  arr = arr.map(function(item) {
    // Stringify the item
    var itemStr = item.join(",");
    // Loop through each item in the array
    arr.forEach(function(compare) {
      // Stringify the item to compare
      var compareStr = compare.join(",");
      // If we're not comparing it to itself, and the rightmost part
      // of the comparison string == the item in question, set the
      // item to the value of "compare"
      if (compareStr != itemStr && 
          compare.join(",").substr(0 - itemStr.length) == itemStr) {
        item = compare;
      }
    });
    return item;
  });
}
```

You could optimize by making a pre-stringified version of all the items in the array.